# simulating pawn jump in the array/vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

Assume we have a vector A of size N.
Pawn starts at A[0] and jumps to index pointed by A[0]: value of A[0] tells how it has to move, i.e: if index is 6.

```
A[6]=1 -> move 1 to the right, to A[7]

A[6]=-2 -> move 2 to the left, to A[4]
```

If pawn gets **to the last index and it is positive**, the pawn gets out of scope 
example:

> > ```
> > A  0 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5
> >    2  -1   4   1   4   2
> > ```

Max value that each element contains is 1 000 000 and N < 1 000 000. function should return 4.

TASK: write a function `int arrayJmp ( const vector<int> &A )`that returns -1 if pawn will never get out of a table or returns number of moves if it will jump out of the array. worst case complexity should be O(n). you can find my answer below. is this right?

Comment: I will put my answer in few minutes

Comment: If you have a working, sufficient answer to this _very localized_, and _not in any way generic_ question, why do you post the question?

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct, and if complexity is achieved

Comment: @ppeterka and I like to post questions, you don't have to participate if you don't want

Comment: @ppeterka do you know what the complexity is?

Comment: @andre or you, do you know?

Comment: @cf16 Ok, but if you have a particular question about your solution, why don't you just put the solution into the question, and ask "is X or Y algorythm more efficient in this case?"

Comment: @ppeterka I don't have to, why should I? because you and few others can't wait 5 mins to downvote?

Comment: @cf16 I did not downvote. You can check my history, if you'd really like to. I rarely ever do that. However, I wanted to help you - thanks, I'll keep that to myself. I just didn't understand you, that's why I asked. That's ok with me as long as its within bounds of rationality.

Comment: sorry then @ppeterka, it were some Java guys for sure and they escaped immediately when code appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>

void myfunction (int &i) {  // function:
  i=1000001;
}

int arrayJmp ( const vector<int> &A ) {
    int N=A.size();

  vector<int> indexes;
  for_each (indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), myfunction);
  int index=0;

  while(std::find(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), index) == indexes.end()){
    indexes.push_back(index);

    index+=A[index];
    if (index==(N-1)&&A[index]>0) return indexes.size()+1;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: So... you just move the pawn according the rules, until either you fall off the right side of the vector or visit some element of the vector for the second time, whichever comes first?

Comment: yes, I count the moves as long as the new index is not present in the previus indexes vector, because if it is present then we will repeat the sequence

Comment: I think this is OK, but maybe exist faster solution?

Comment: Maybe there is, but this solution makes N moves in the worst case (when it has to visit every element of the vector), so it's O(n). Btw, `if (A[index] >= N - index)` would be a bit more relaible, I guess...

Comment: index==(N-1)&&A[index]>0  is OK, I don't understand

Comment: What if `index == N-2` and `A[N-2] == 7`? My teachers used to like to give our programs improper input and watch them burn.

Comment: if pawn gets to the last index and it is positive, the pawn gets out of scope - > only from last index

Comment: But what if it gets to the second from the last index and the element at that index is equal or greater than 2?

Comment: it is said that such situation won't take place but yes, this might have happened then and changed would be required to my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'table', 'array' and 'vector' interchangeably?

The request is quite simple:

```
if ((i = array[  index ]) < 0 || i >= sizeof(array)) ;//out of bounds

otherwise i is within bounds
```

Comment: Office let me copy and paste: write a function int arrayJmp ( const vector<int> &A )

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int jump_array(const std::vector<int>& vector)
{
    int index = 0;
    int old_index = 0;
    int size = vector.size();
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        old_index = index;
        index += vector[index];
        if(count >= size)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    while(index < size);

    return vector[old_index];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(2);
    vector.push_back(-1);
    vector.push_back(4);
    vector.push_back(1);
    vector.push_back(4);
    vector.push_back(2);

    std::cout << jump_array(vector);
}
```

Comment: will not return -1 immediately if sequence repeats, I think my solution is faster. or not?